# how to get a sorted file content with sh under OpenWrt?

Tags: linux, sorting, sh, openwrt

I have a file that contain the following content:

```
type1
type2
type4
type15
type13
type10
type9
type8
type3
type5
type6
type7
type11
type12
type14
```

I used this command to get a sorted content `cat file|sort -u`

but I have the following result:

```
$cat file|sort -u
type1
type10
type11
type12
type13
type14
type15
type2
type3
type4
type5
type6
type7
type8
type9
```

What is the right command to get the following result?

```
type1
type2
type3
type4
type5
type6
type7
type8
type9
type10
type11
type12
type13
type14
type15
```

This my sort command help:

```
root@router:~# sort --help
BusyBox v1.19.2 (2013-05-20 07:23:28 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: sort [-nru] [FILE]...

Sort lines of text

        -n      Sort numbers
        -r      Reverse sort order
        -u      Suppress duplicate lines
```

Comment: With 01, 02, 03, 04, ... it works.

Comment: I see, but my data have the above format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coreutils-sort package.

```
opkg install coreutils-sort -force-overwrite
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
sort -u -k 1.5n file
```

The `-k` option specifies the sort key. `1.5` means that it starts from character 5 of column 1 of the input, and `n` means that it should do a numeric sort instead of lexicographic.

Comment: I use sh in openwrt and I have not the -k option, I have updated my post you can see it

Comment: Your version of sort is very deficient, it's missing many standard options. Since it's Linux, you should be able to install GNU sort.